# How to apply an array through an input with type=text to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I want to write an array like `[1, 2, 3]` into the text input on the html page and by clicking on the button apply it to the `var array` of the function called `inputArray().`
I tried to do so using

```
var array=document.querySelector("#inputNumber").value;
```

but that doesn't apply it as an array, just as a string I guess.
The other function called `numbeRray(array)` will then check if the array only consists of numbers.
Right now it checks if the single characters of the string are numbers because I wasn't able to add an array yet...

```js
function numbeRray(array) {
  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    if (isNaN(array[a])) {
      throw new Error('The element in position ' + (a + 1) + ' of the array is not a number');
    }
  }
}

function inputArray() {
  var array=document.querySelector("#inputNumber").value;
  try {
    numbeRray(array);
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
    return;
  }
  alert(array);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputNumber"/>

<button type="button" onclick="inputArray();">Check Array</button>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you will type into your text field? For example, are you typing `1,2,3` or 1 2 3`, or what?

Comment: [1, 2, 3] for example, including the box brackets

Comment: You can't do that. The value of a text input will always be a string. Try `JSON.parse(val)` after you get the value from the input

Comment: You will need to parse that string into it's parts, and do a `parseInt()`on each part, then `.push()` it into the array. That's one way. ... A quicker way, would be to `eval()` it (though probably not recommended unless you sanitize the string first).

Comment: But @lastr2d2, the input string is not JSON.

Comment: `[1,2,3]` is a valid input value for `JSON.parse`

Comment: I stand corrected. @lastr2d2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function numbeRray(array) {
  try {
    array = JSON.parse(array);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Invalid input.")
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
    throw new Error("Not array.")
  }
  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    if (typeof array[a] !== 'number' || isNaN(array[a])) {
      throw new Error('Das Element an Position ' + (a + 1) + ' des Arrays ist keine Zahl');
    }
  }
}

function inputArray() {
  var array=document.querySelector("#inputNumber").value;
  try {
    numbeRray(array);
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
    return;
  }
  alert(array);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Fehlerbehandlung</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="inputNumber"/>

<button type="button" onclick="inputArray();">Check Array</button>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code6.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Since the input is a json, Use `JSON.parse` to convert it to the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I fixed it by updating the variable called array to ```var array=JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#inputNumber").value);``` Now it is working the way I wanted.